# Testing unfriendly code

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Say I have the following code, which cannot be modified:

```java
class A {
    public doSomething() {
        // lots of business logic
        data = obtainData();
        // lots of other business logic which depends on data
    }

    private obtainData() {
        // connect to the database
        // send web requests
        // send manned missions to the moon
        // process the obtained data
        return data;
    }
}
```

What are the best practices of testing such a code? I want to make sure `doSomething()` does what it should do, but I want to provide it with known data instead of running the code inside `obtainData()`.

Comment: Private instead of protected... Ouch. :-(

Comment: @Denis: what's wrong with private?

Comment: @zerkms: If it were protected, he could declare a class B that extends A and redefine obtainData(). Depending on the language he's using, he might not be able to do that with a private method.

Comment: Private is ok, many variables are better set as untouchable.

Comment: I'm pro-private. As long as there's dependency injection.

Comment: I'm putting this as a comment because I basically answered this already in your other question. If there is hardcoded function calls in obtainData, you redefine the functions (TestHelper extension). If you create new classes in there, you intercept the instantiation (TestHelper extension). If there is any other calls to dependencies (static or otherwise=, you just mock them with the regular mocking functions of phpunit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) to help you with brownfield testing.  Moles in C# allow you provide your own implementations for private code and other people's code.

When you have a good set of tests that cover this mess, please [re-factor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321603508) to save humanity.

If the originator of the spaghetti code is within reach, please smack him for me, why don't ya?

For best practices, read Uncle Bob's Clean Code [http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

To summarize: if code under test has external dependencies, make them explicit and externally-configurable.

Comment: "Brown" sounds just right! What I'm asking though, is for best practices in general. How would something like this be tested with regular unit tests.

Comment: @rdineiu: original question did not include a specific language or technology.  I am providing a generic answer.

Comment: @GregC, that's OK. Generic is what I'm asking for. So the answer is that it's best practice to, if possible, rip out the private method and replace it with something else, or, if not possible, don't test. Right?

Comment: @rdineiu: (and i thought you're on my side) Test, test, and test again.  If it's not possible to test, your tools are weak.

Comment: @GregC, (it wasn't me who downvoted...) and if tools are weak (because the language doesn't support this kind of esoteric magic), make your own to rip a hole in space / time, or in the way the language works, and extract the damned method?

Comment: @rdineiu: I would not do anything to the method itself in fear of breaking it, but would make sure i can pass all external dependencies as parameters into it.  Then test it through public interface with stubs.

Comment: @GregC, if I could change the public interface, there are still 2 problems remaining: 1. this private method has 1 million dependencies, 2. it has logic of its own. So even if I provide all the mocked dependencies, I still have no control of what it returns. I could tweak the mocks in such a way that it would make the private method return what I want, but is this the way to do it?

Comment: You must exercise all reachable code paths thru that private method.  That's the idea. The rest is implementation details.

Comment: But it's not the private method I want to test... At the moment it's just an inconvenience. I don't care what it does, nor how the things it uses work, I just care for it to return what I need to test the method that I need to test...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the offending code, usually the culprits are new object creation in constructer, static calls, use of constants, and a few others.

The idea is to decouple your class from it's dependencies. The common way of doing this is  by dependency-injection.

Also consider having smaller classes that do very specific tasks, chance are if you describe your class task with an "and" in the sentence, it does too much and will be harder to test.

See [this post](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html) and all related links on it for information relative to testing static and hard-coded dependencies.

Comment: I was looking at that, and I was considering making the private method accessible through the black voodoo magic provided by the latest PHP 5.3 (my code happens to be PHP), but is this the correct way of handling this? It somehow seems... pretty ugly... How would you do this in a language that doesn't provide the magic necessary for exposing that private method? Or you just wouldn't?

Comment: Had a few posts myself on this exact subject. You should NEVER have to test your private methods and variables. There are exceptions, but even those reflect a bad design. You should test the public methods, and these will validate the private are working as expected. You will 1. Save time, 2. Have more meaningful code coverage reports 3. Enjoy unit testing way more.

Like I said, having too many things to test on a class means it needs to be split into smaller classes with distinct responsibilites, making for easier mocking and reducing the expected results of this class, thus, less tests.

Comment: You don't have to convince me, I'm a fan of dependency injection and decoupling. But unfortunately we don't live in a perfect world, and sometimes we need to inherit bad code (and when I say *bad*, I'm diplomatic). But it needs to be tested nonetheless...

Answer (score 0):

Work on the design

1. Identify the responsibilities of this class.
2. Next, Extract the dependencies of this class. Move all methods that do not align with bullet#1 into a dependency.

e.g. if this class is not responsible for handling databases or network IO, extract them as dependencies of this class. Inject them as ctor args or method args(if only a single public method needs it).

```
public A(DataRepository repository, WebService service, SpaceStation spaceStation)
{ // cache them as internal fields;}
```

Now it is not necessary to stub out or subclass and override or increase member visibility for testing.

Your unit tests would create an instance as

```
_testSubject = new A(new Mock<DataRepository>.object, new Mock<WebService>.object, new Mock<SpaceStation>.object);
```

whereas your production code would use real implementations of the above roles.

Comment: The idea is to move the unfriendly bits / awkward dependencies behind roles that you can mock/substitute in your tests.

Answer (score -1):

Have you had a look at Mocking? It might be provided by your unit testing framework.

Comment: I know about mocking. But how would I create a mock for testing this class? What should I mock?

Comment: Partial mocking is not available in all testing FWs. In phpunit there is no.